# MySQL for Excel TIME Column

Tags: mysql, excel, time

I wanted to check in here to see if anyone has any suggestions before submitting a bug report to Oracle.

I'm using MySQL for Excel in Excel 2013, and when trying to import a table that has a TIME type column, the import fails and I get the following error message:

```
An error occurred when trying to import the data.
Method's type signature is not Interop compatible.
```

I looked up information about `Method's type signature is not Interop compatible.` but found only things relating to C/C#.

I'm trying to insert data that is formatted as a relative time duration, e.g. 00:02:34 (2 minutes 34 seconds), but I cannot find a way to do this. MySQL for Excel won't import a TIME column, and when I define the column as VARCHAR, it does some calculation on each value when it's submitted to the database; 00:02:34 ends up as 0.00178240740740741 in the database.

Is there a different column type that I can use that will leave a string like 00:00:00 unformatted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because excel can't handle the conversion of that data type so what is being reported... the .001782... is the time in days.  So if you take 24*60*60* that number you get your 2:34...

When importing to Excel you can append a single quote ' to the beginning of the string value. This kept the formatting in the cell; but it may cause problems with the data later when you have to pull the ' off for processing.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but I'm looking for a solution. Any idea how I can get the value I need from Excel to MySQL? I guess I'll look into custom column types.

Comment: I copied the 0.001782... to an excel cell and changed the format to time XX:XX:XX... This displayed 00:02:34.  Is this what you're after a formating on excel?  I then could copy hte value and paste special retaining the number format but this seems like overkill.  If you know that the number being displayed is the fractional part of a day, and a time format in excel displays what you're wanting to see, I can't see why you'd need to retain the formatting as 00:00:00 in excel.

Comment: In a sense, yes. But I think I'm out of luck, as I can't get excel to send that value to MySQL without calculating it into a decimal value. Changing the column type in Excel to Time seems to be superficial only. I'll format the decimal value as you suggest. Thanks for taking the time to look into it with me.

Answer (score 0):

This issue in MySQL for Excel was fixed [at least partially] since version 1.3.0, when you choose to a Create Excel Table on the Advanced Options menu of the Import Dialog. (If you leave that option unchecked the error still appears.)

A bug report with a similar description of the error message you describe has been raised to the MySQL team in charge of MySQL for Excel. If you wanna receive updates on this please feel free to suscribe to Email Updates in this link: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72504